# Can the USB interface IC be identified via code alone?

Tags: usb

I know that the master controller can be found in verbose upload output in IDE, but I have a few boards from different manufacturers and my smartphone camera is apparently insufficient to take a legible picture. Is there something I can do from the PC, either via official IDE or otherwise, that will return usb controller chipset?

Comment: did you look into driver details in Windows Device Manager?

Comment: Which property do I need?, meaninng, there is a dropdown under Property, Which option contains the chip? 
c
ETA:N/M It's Driver Description. If you write an answer I will accept.

Comment: If the Device Manager does not give a sufficient answer directly, it tells you the VID:PID combination that identifies each USB device. Use this numbers to ask your favorite web search engine.